# Relationship between conjoint measurement and conjoint analysis

Tags: history, conjoint-analysis

The wikipedia page "Cojoint Analysis" says that conjoint analysis originated in mathematical psychology (without a reference) but also that it was developed by marketing professor Paul Green. On the german wikipedia site Luce and Tukey are mentioned as the originators with the following article: https://www.imbs.uci.edu/files/personnel/luce/pre1990/1964/LuceTukey_JMP_1964.pdf (https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1016/0022-2496(64)90015-X)

But this article is about conjoint measurement, a theory for testing whether a variable is quantitative. What exactly is the relationship between conjoint measurement and conjoint analysis?